# Urdu characters joining problem

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write Urdu language characters in a div using javascript. The problem is that they dont change their shape when i write two characters that should have different shape when written together. For example ﺝ and ا when written together should look as جا. They dont merge with each other. Similar is the problem with other characters. Please help!

Comment: What code are you using?

Comment: Looks like one is U+062C, and the other is U+FE9D. Is this deliberate?

Comment: I'm using unicode. There codes are &#x62C and the other is &#x627. When i select them together in charmap (windows utility), they join and make a different shape. But when i create them myself in javascript they are not joining in div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. Actually I was copying other characters that visually looked the same but where not the one I needed. For example, one character from urdu and other from arabic will not join properly. So whenever copying characters, even if they look same, do consider that they may have different unicodes for different languages.

Comment: Well wasimBhalli can you throw on some light how were you able to join the characters ?

Comment: When searching for a book, the user can select Urdu language, you can see the JavaScript code for it